# Restricting Windows server RDP access to VPN

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-firewall

I want to configure a remote server (Windows 2012) to allow only access using RDP via VPN. Therefore I should restrict access to the public IP of the server and only allow the private IP access. In addition I would need the port 80 to be open for public. All the other ports should be closed from the public.

I need to do this for security reasons as there are a lot of login attempts.

I tried to make a rule as a test to block an IP address, and then allow it in another rule. The rule that overrides the other is to block an IP. Therefore I cannot make a rule to block every IP, and another to allow only the specified, only a rule in which I can allow every IP and block the specified.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to alter the Firewall rule for RDP to only use 'Remote' interfaces

In the firewall rule for RDP goto `Advanced` and customize the interface type to only `remote access`

If the server is truly remote, say on Azure, make sure you can still access the server via another means when setting this up in case there are issues are you are locked out! Can always remove this once its all working.